# UITextView links that are heterogeneously styled are not completely highlighted when touched

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitextview, nsattributedstring

When the user taps on a link in a textView, the whole link should highlight. But if the link text is not homogeneously styled, it highlights only up to the parts of the link text that has the same attributes beginning from the first character.

Here is code example:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* someAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This style, that style"];
[someAttrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10] range:NSMakeRange(0, 11)];
[someAttrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] range:NSMakeRange(12, 8)];
[someAttrString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"http://www.apple.com" range:NSMakeRange(0, someAttrString.length)];
someUITextView.attributedText = someAttrString;
```

(I don't have the reputation to post images of this, even though I want to show what the bug looks like visually)

Is there a workaround for this thing? I need to style my links is a specific way and not have it look weird when the user taps on it.

Answer (score 0):

1st Solution thats easy : This will help you [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel)

2nd Solution :

> NSAttributedString* attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
>   initWithString:@"www.google.com" attributes:@{ @"LINK_CUSTOM" :
>   @"www.google.com" }]; [paragraph
>   appendAttributedString:attributedString];

Add UITapGesture to UITextView

> - (void)textTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
>     UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)recognizer.view;
>
>   // Location of the tap in text-container coordinates
>
>   NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = textView.layoutManager;
>     CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:textView];
>     location.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left;
>     location.y -= textView.textContainerInset.top;
>
>   NSUInteger characterIndex;
>     characterIndex = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:location
>                                            inTextContainer:textView.textContainer
>                   fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:NULL];
>
>   if (characterIndex < textView.textStorage.length) {
>
>   ```
>   NSRange range;
>   id value = [textView.attributedText attribute:@"LINK_CUSTOM" atIndex:characterIndex effectiveRange:&range];
>   ```
>
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[value
>   stringValue]]];
>
> ```
> } }
> ```